# Why do I care that smooth vector fields over a smooth manifold have a Lie algebra?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

So, I know the following facts:

1. A Lie group is a group and a Manifold, whose group structure is continuous with respect to the Manifold structure
2. The Lie algebra is a vector space with a Lie bracket structure on it.
3. Every Lie group has a corresponding Lie algebra.
4. The Lie algebra represents the "infinitesimal behaviour" of the Lie group.

Till here, stuff makes sense. However, *this* is where I lose it:

5. The Vector space of all Vector fields over a Manifold form a Lie algebra with the [Lie bracket of vector fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields) structure.

Why do I care about fact 5? Is it because it is "cute" that the Lie bracket exists? What do I gain by showing that vector fields have a lie bracket structure?

Comment: If the manifold is a Lie group, then you can take the left-invariant vector fields, show that these are closed under the bracket structure on all vector fields on the manifold, and this will be the Lie algebra of the group. I guess that's cute?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)

Comment: @Joppy "...this will _be_ the Lie algebra of the group" - Is that not the _definition_ of the Lie algebra of the Lie group? I was asking more about the Lie algebra of a general manifold (which is _not_ a Lie group)

Comment: It's _a_ definition of the Lie algebra of a Lie group, but another one is for example the tangent space at the identity, with the bracket induced by the differential of the conjugation map.

Comment: @Joppy - could you please expand on this comment with an answer? I have not seen this equivalent definition, and would be nice if you could expand on what you said :)

Comment: Page 118 of [these notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LAG.pdf) has a construction of the Lie algebra of an algebraic group using this method. I'm about 70% sure it works for manifolds as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't answer the question in your title -- maybe you just *don't* care. ;-)

But I'll tell you some reasons why I find it interesting and useful.

1. First, and perhaps deepest, is that you can view the group of
   all diffeomorphisms of a smooth manifold $M$ as an
   infinite-dimensional Fréchet Lie group, and its Lie algebra is
   exactly $\mathfrak X(M)$ with its Lie bracket structure (see [this
   article](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1982-15004-2) by Richard Hamilton for a beautiful exposition of this
   point of view).
2. Second, any smooth right action by a (finite-dimensional) Lie group
   $G$ on $M$ determines a Lie algebra homomorphism from
   $\operatorname{Lie}(G)$ to $\mathfrak X(M)$, sending $X\in
   \operatorname{Lie}(G)$ to the vector field $\widehat X\in \mathfrak
   X(M)$ defined by $$ \widehat X_p = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}
   p\cdot \exp tX. $$ Conversely, given any finite-dimensional Lie
   subalgebra $\mathfrak g\subset \mathfrak X(M)$ with the property
   that every vector field in $\mathfrak g$ is complete, there is a
   smooth right action of the simply connected Lie group $G$ whose Lie
   algebra is isomorphic to $\mathfrak g$, and $\mathfrak g$ is the
   image of the Lie algebra homomorphism described above. (See pp.
   525-530 of my *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* [[ISM](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds.html?id=eqfgZtjQceYC)].)
3. You can think of the Lie algebra structure of $\mathfrak
   X(M)$ as providing obstructions to commutativity of flows: Two
   smooth flows on $M$ commute if and only if their infinitesimal
   generators have zero Lie bracket [[ISM](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds.html?id=eqfgZtjQceYC), Thm. 9.44].
4. If $M$ is endowed with a complete Riemannian metric, the set of all Killing vector fields is a finite-dimensional Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak X(M)$, which is the Lie algebra of the full isometry group of $M$.
5. In the presence of a symplectic structure, there is a map
   from $C^\infty(M)$ to $\mathfrak X(M)$ sending $f$ to its
   [Hamiltonian vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field) $X_f$, which gives a Lie algebra
   isomorphism (or anti-isomorphism, depending on your conventions)
   between $C^\infty(M)/\{\text{constants}\}$ with its [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket)
   structure and a certain Lie subalgebra $\mathscr H(M)\subseteq \mathfrak X(M)$, the algebra of Hamiltonian vector fields. This is in turn a subalgebra of a larger Lie subalgebra $\mathscr S(M)\subseteq \mathfrak X(M)$, the *symplectic vector fields*, and the quotient $\mathscr S(M)/\mathscr H(M)$ is naturally isomorphic to the first de Rham cohomology of $M$. (See, for example, [[ISM](https://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Smooth_Manifolds.html?id=eqfgZtjQceYC), Chap. 22].) The Lie algebra structure of $\mathscr H(M)$ plays a central role in dynamical systems, for example in identifying completely integrable systems and in Noether's theorem about the relationship between symmetries and conserved quantities.
6. The Frobenius theorem says that a smooth distribution (i.e., vector subbundle) $D\subseteq TM$ is tangent to a [foliation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliation) if and only if the set of smooth sections of $D$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak X(M)$. [Thanks to Jason deVito for suggesting this one.]
7. And of course I shouldn't leave out the one most directly related to Lie groups -- if $G$ is a Lie group, then the Lie algebra of $G$ is naturally realized as the Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak g\subset \mathfrak X(G)$ consisting of left-invariant vector fields. [Pointed out by @Joppy in comments above.]

I'm convinced -- are you?

Comment: Wow, thanks for this in-depth answer! In particular, (3) is a direct, intuitive reason for caring. (1) is a deep, crazy reason :)

Comment: Oh wow, I'm reading your book. Thanks a lot for writing it, it's very well written (I love the exposition), and the exercises are fun to do as well!

Comment: @SiddharthBhat: You're welcome! And thanks for the kind compliment.

Comment: I would only add one thing to this fantastic answer:  The Frobenius theorem tells you exactly when a distribution comes from a submanifold, and it's tied directly to the Lie algebra strcture on $\mathfrak X(M)$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Great suggestion! I'll add that to my list.